# Exchange route mail to internal smart host

Tags: email, exchange, smarthost

We have a BI/ETL tool which is capable of triggering tasks on receipt of an email. We have a number of servers set up running this tool. Each is configured as an IIS 'smart host'.

We currently use a commercial spam tool to route emails sent to a specific email address to these smart hosts.

Is anyone aware of a way to do this within Exchange, or even via an alternative commercial tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *ForwardingSMTPAddress* property to forward e-mails to a specific e-mail address. Run the following command in the EMS (Exchange Management Shell)

```
Set-Mailbox username -ForwardingSMTPAddress emailaddress@domain.com -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $True
```

If you want to keep an e-mail in your inbox, set the *DeliverToMailboxAndForward* to true.

Comment: Thanks, I know about this EMS cmdlet. My problem is that it needs to forward to an IIS smart host, not another exchange user r address...

Comment: Just setup a dummy domain then.
Have that dummy domain configured on a Send Connector with the smart host configured as part of that Send Connector.

Comment: If I understand you correctly than you want to have Sender based routing on Exchange. However this function doesn't exist anymore since Exchange 2003, however you can setup a new domain and some contacts and use the ForwardingSMTPAddress as @Sembee mentioned above or you use a third-party tool as the one you're using now.